# Need to add "exe" version info to a mobile device exe created in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile, vb6

I want to add version info to my mobile device exe file and apparently the following line is not supported in CF (windows mobile 6.0), ideas?:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

I want to be able to to right-click on the `.exe` after it is copied over to the PC and have the version displayed in a `version` tab just like any other `.exe`. I would then be able to read this version in code from a VB6 program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the AssemblyFileVersion, which the CF doesn't support.  See [this blog entry](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2004/11/assemblyfileversion-on-cf.html) for a workaround.  FWIW, the link he gives to Neil's blog [is now here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/Trackback,guid,e5babf15-ebb3-47b0-b072-957e6f3ccc85.aspx).

Comment: I added the code changes, then re-compiled, but when I right-click the exe in Explorer and go to Properties there is still no "Version" tab.

Comment: You made sure to add the AssemblyFileVersion Attribute to your AssemblyInfo as well, right?